# Ansible - delete files on a remote NTFS file share

Tags: powershell, ansible, share

I need to create a playbook that will delete files older then X days on a remote share location which has Windows NTFS share permissions. Account that can access the share is AD service account (different then the one used for Ansible). Ansible is Tower version with RedHat as OS. There is no PowerShell host which I can use as intermediary.

There is a win-share-module https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_share_module.html#ansible-collections-ansible-windows-win-share-module but host that execute module must be Windows not Linux.

There is also ansible.windows.win_powershell module, but for this I have to install PowerShell in Ansible Tower, right?

What would be the best and easiest you would do it?

UPDATE

Let me add that I installed powershell on Linux but when doing this basic test

```yaml
    ---
    - name: Delete old PowerFlex storage backups 
      hosts: localhost
      gather_facts: no
      connection: local
    
      tasks:
        - name: Run basic PowerShell script
          ansible.windows.win_powershell:
            script: |
              echo "Hello World"
```

I get the error

> "module_stderr": "/bin/sh: powershell: command not found\n",

On the other hand when I login to linux CLI, I can enter into PowerShell with pwsh (not powershell), so I guess this module calls different version of PowerShell.

What is a workaround on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `win_powershell` module is not going to work on your Tower machine. It will only work on windows OS.

Since you need to run this script a linux hosts, you can use [shell](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html) module, and specify the executable path to wherever pwsh is on your machine. I would use a script for easier development/testing, but you can also use direct commands.

```yaml
- name: execute pwsh
  ansible.builtin.shell: /path/to/Invoke-Script.ps1
  args:
    executable: /bin/pwsh
```